# Number of equations and number of variables in system of polynomial equations

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, systems-of-equations, real-algebraic-geometry

It is well known that if we have a system of linear equations of $n$ variables, we need $n$ equations to solve the system. I wonder if we can say the same thing for a system of polynomial equations of $n$ variable? More specifically, I have an assumption that this system has one and only one real solution. It seems like the answer is yes, but what could be a rigorous way to prove it, or at least to reason about it?

In addition, the above requirement for linear systems also assumes the $n$ equations are linearly independent. What would be an equivalent statement if we were to analyze the system of polynomial equations?

For context, I am trying to analyze the complexity of a learning algorithm that boils down to solve a system of polynomial equations. I would like to know how many (and what kind of) equations the algorithm needs to construct in order to find the (unique) solution as this helps quantify the complexity. I do not need to actually solve this system.

As suggested by @Ethan, adding a concrete example: think of an example that we try to do parameter estimation using the method of moments, $\mathbb E[X^i]=f_i(\theta), \theta\in \Theta \subseteq \mathbb R^n, i\in\mathbb N^+$ where all the moments $f$ are polynomial functions of $\theta$. Given the ground truth value of all the moments, the goal is to solve for $\theta$ (though how to solve is not within the scope of the discussion). Assume the model is identifiable (i.e. the system has a unique solution), how many such "moments equation" do we need in order to solve the system? Is it the first $n$ moments?

Comment: $x^2=1$ has 1 variable, 1 equation, but 2 solutions

Comment: If you want to know more about the set of solutions of a system of polynomials, you should study what is an ideal. When you work on a algebraically closed field, having exactly one solution corresponds to have a maximal ideal generated by your equations

Comment: I am not asking about the number of roots though (or the condition of the system to have one root). I am assuming there exists a unique real solution, possibly in some subspace of $\mathbb R^n$. For what I am asking, in your example, we have 1 variable, and we only need one equation to solve for it.

Comment: What about the system of equations: $$x^2 + y^2 = 5$$ $$x^2 + y^2 = 6.$$  This system represents two non-intersecting circles in $\Bbb{R^2}.$  In $\Bbb{R^2}$, two circles (for example) can intersect in either $(0)$ points, $(1)$ point, $(2)$ points or an infinite number of points (i.e. when the two equations yield the same circle).  I think that attempting to analyze which systems of (potentially non-linear) polynomial equations yield a unique solution is *no walk in the park*.

Comment: This is a complex problem vaguely expressed. If you [edit] the question to show us several examples of the kinds of sets of polynomials you are thinking about we might be able to help.

Comment: I am not trying to analyze what system yields a unique solution. I am assuming that the system has a unique solution is a given condition. Think of an example doing parameter estimation using the method of moments, $\mathbb E[X^i]=f(\theta), \theta\in \mathbb R^n, i\in\mathbb N^+$ where all the moments $f$ are polynomial functions of $\theta$. Given that I know the oracle of all the moments, I want to solve for $\theta$. Assume the model is identifiable (i.e. the system has a unique solution), how many such "moments equation" do I need in order to solve the system? Is it the first $n$ moments?

Comment: Sorry for a typo above, should be $\mathbb E[X^i]=f_i(\theta)$.

Comment: You might be interested in the study of [gröbner bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis). The algorithms for gröbner bases generalize row reduction (which solves equations in linear algebra) to general polynomials. The price you pay for this flexibility is that the theory is much harder, and the kinds of nice "n equations and n unknowns" theorems are no longer true, though there are special cases. If you're interested in this, you might try Cox, Little, and O'Shea's _Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms_ or Adams and Loustaunau's _An Introduction to Gröbner Bases_

Comment: VERY broadly and inaccurately speaking, "n polynomial equations in n variables have a finite number of solutions" holds, so if you KNOW there's only a solution, it's ok. The condition of the determinant translates into "the generated ideal is maximal" as said before.

Comment: What if I change the question to "how many equations do we need to solve for any solution in a system of polynomial equations of $n$ variables", regardless real or complex, assuming there exists at least one real or complex solution?